# Finding a URL within two strings regex

Tags: regex

I have a long HTML file that contains the names of organizations and their URL's. Each organization's "section" in the code is demarcated by the word "organization" followed by a lot of code, with their URL located inside that code, and ends with the word "organization".

For example:

organization -- a lot of code (with the URL located somewhere inside) -- organization

I have tried to use regex to search and extract the URL, but to no avail.

```
organization(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\ @/$,]*organization
```

I suspect my problem lies somewhere in my trying to demarcate the search for URL's by just using the word "organization", but I am not sure.

Comment: `organization.*?` ... rest of regex ...`.*organization`, if you can let the `.` also match newlines, otherwise it's probably `organization(.|\s)*?` etc.

Comment: Can you show us an *actual* example?  Something we can test our solutions against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try group 1 from this:

```
organization.*\b(\w+://[\w.?%&=@/$,-]+).*?organization
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex is searching for something sandwiched immediately between two instances of "organization". If there's any chance of characters existing between "organization" and your URL, you'll need to introduce a non-greedy match for any instances of anything (`.*?`), and if there are newlines in the mix you'll need to use `(?:.|\n)*?`.

So your regex becomes:
`organization`**`(?:.|\n)*?`**`(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\ @/$,]*`**`(?:.|\n)*?`**`organization`

(Because of the **bold** insertions, this mistakenly *appears* to have spaces, but it does not. If you select it and copy/paste, it will paste correctly without spaces)

Comment: Well, as ghoti pointed out in the comments, we have no way of testing, because you've not provided any sort of examples. At this point, all we can do is take stabs in the dark.